# Is the San Ysidro PedWest crossing closed?

Tags: borders, mexico, walking, san-diego

Regarding the [San Ysidro PedWest crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=San_Ysidro_Port_of_Entry&oldid=966313487#PedWest_(western_pedestrian_crossing)), I read:

- https://bwt.cbp.gov/details/09250407/PED ([mirror](https://archive.vn/gOcfG)) says "Current Wait: Lanes Closed" and "Hours of Operation: 24 hrs/day  Date: 9/25/2020", and the graph displays and flat 0-minute waiting time throughout the day, which seems to indicate all lanes are closed hrs/day.
- https://goo.gl/maps/Vhv37YFhgAkqi3sb7 ([mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgWv1.jpg)) says it is opened between 4 AM to 10 PM.
- https://www.10news.com/news/local-news/new-coronavirus-testing-side-opening-along-u-s-mexico-border ([mirror](https://archive.is/QOBPM)) (published on 2020-08-09) seems to imply it was open by the time the article was published.
- https://www.newsbreak.com/california/san-diego/news/1541178199258/pedwest-crossing-temporarily-closed-as-part-of-changes-at-the-california-mexico-border
  ([mirror](https://archive.vn/fgNqO)) (published on 2020-04-04) says "U.S. Customs and Border Protection has made changes at ports of entry along the California-Mexico border, including the temporary closure of the PedWest pedestrian crossing, in response to decreases in traffic since the coronavirus-related restrictions to non-essential travel took place."

I am getting confused. Is the [San Ysidro PedWest crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=San_Ysidro_Port_of_Entry&oldid=966313487#PedWest_(western_pedestrian_crossing)) currently closed? If so, when is it scheduled to reopen, and if not what are the hours of operations?

Comment: Here's the original press release from CBP: https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/local-media-release/san-diego-cbp-officials-are-announcing-changes-hours-operations-select

Comment: I checked the county covid-19 test sites, assuming that the San Ysidro site would be included. There is one at "PedEast". There's none listed at PedWest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PedWest port of entry is still closed, having closed on April 5, 2020 until further notice.

It was closed in response to the reduced border crossings due to Covid-19, and while temporary the CBP still say "until further notice"

> Pedwest Temporary Closure
> Due to decreases in pedestrian traffic since
> the coronavirus-related restrictions to non-essential travel took
> place, a decision was made to temporary close the PedWest pedestrian
> border crossing. These changes will go into effect tomorrow, Sunday
> April 5th, 2020 and remain closed on a temporary basis until further
> notice.

See [announcement on PedWest Border Crossing Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/PedWestBorder/posts/2707594182807941)

See also:

[CBP Border Wait times page](https://bwt.cbp.gov/details/09250407/PED) for PedWest which states it's closed

[image]

[CBP Official Press Release](https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/local-media-release/san-diego-cbp-officials-are-announcing-changes-hours-operations-select)

Be aware that the Pedestrian Ports of Entry at [PedEast San Ysidro](https://goo.gl/maps/VT1auCfqnx773z6bA), and at [Otay Mesa](https://goo.gl/maps/cLeX7hPEiNttbQ5Q8) are still operating, so if you need to cross on foot you can still do so.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused as the webpage you took a screenshot of also says "hours of Operation: 24 hrs/day". By the way any idea why gmaps says "it is opened between 4 AM to 10 PM."? were the hour of operations reduced from 24 hrs/day to 4 AM-10 PM before it got closed?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I've never used PedWest, only PedEast and Otay, however I wonder whether the confusion may be that the CBP offices are probably/possibly open, but the actual Port of Entry is closed.  So you can go to the CBP there, but you can't cross the border.

Comment: got it, that'd make sense indeed

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Additionally the CBP is updating the status of the border restrictions (which would include the PedWest closure) each month on around the 16-20th of each month, so potentially the writers of some of your links may have expected the borders to reopen sooner.